# Using cometD's Oort with tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, asynchronous, cometd

We are using cometD with Tomcat 7.0.42 (which is a must). We now try to get Oort (the clustering mechanism of cometD) working. If I enabled Oort in the web.xml like this, each time another node tries to connect the exception below occures.

I am well aware that cometD currently can't use Websockets with Tomcat which is why I would esxpect cometD to simply fall back to longpolling...

This is my config:

```
  <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
<display-name>messenger</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.cometd.server.CometdServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allowedTransports</param-name>
        <param-value>LongPollingTransport</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>timeout</param-name>
        <param-value>20000</param-value>
    </init-param>


    <init-param>
        <param-name>jsonContext</param-name>
        <param-value>org.cometd.server.JacksonJSONContextServer</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>maxInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>10000</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>long-polling.multiSessionInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>2000</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Oort</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.cometd.oort.OortStaticConfigServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>oort.url</param-name>
        <param-value>http://192.168.178.37:8080/messenger/cometd</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>oort.channels</param-name>
        <param-value>/messenger/**,/internal/**</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>oort.cloud</param-name>
        <param-value>http://192.168.178.22:8080/messenger/cometd</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Seti</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.cometd.oort.SetiServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

And this is the exception:

```
org.cometd.common.TransportException: {httpCode=400, websocketCode=1002}
at org.cometd.websocket.client.WebSocketTransport.connect(WebSocketTransport.java:287) ~[cometd-websocket-jetty-2.7.0.jar:na]
at org.cometd.websocket.client.WebSocketTransport.send(WebSocketTransport.java:194) ~[cometd-websocket-jetty-2.7.0.jar:na]
at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient$BayeuxClientState.send(BayeuxClient.java:1390) ~[cometd-java-client-2.7.0.jar:na]
at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient.sendHandshake(BayeuxClient.java:374) ~[cometd-java-client-2.7.0.jar:na]
at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient$HandshakingState.execute(BayeuxClient.java:1496) ~[cometd-java-client-2.7.0.jar:na]
at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient.updateBayeuxClientState(BayeuxClient.java:1062) ~[cometd-java-client-2.7.0.jar:na]
at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient.handshake(BayeuxClient.java:315) ~[cometd-java-client-2.7.0.jar:na]
at org.cometd.oort.Oort.connectComet(Oort.java:411) ~[cometd-java-oort-2.7.0.jar:na]
at org.cometd.oort.Oort.observeComet(Oort.java:358) ~[cometd-java-oort-2.7.0.jar:na]
at org.cometd.oort.Oort.observeComet(Oort.java:306) ~[cometd-java-oort-2.7.0.jar:na]
at org.cometd.oort.OortMulticastConfigurer.receive(OortMulticastConfigurer.java:125) ~[cometd-java-oort-2.7.0.jar:na]
at org.cometd.oort.OortMulticastConfigurer$MulticastReceiver.run(OortMulticastConfigurer.java:154) ~[cometd-java-oort-2.7.0.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) ~[na:1.7.0_25]

Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Bad response status 400 Bad Request
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketClientFactory$HandshakeConnection.onClose(WebSocketClientFactory.java:546) ~[jetty-websocket-8.1.5.v20120716.jar:8.1.5.v20120716]
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketClientFactory$WebSocketClientSelector.endPointClosed(WebSocketClientFactory.java:326) ~[jetty-websocket-8.1.5.v20120716.jar:8.1.5.v20120716]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.destroyEndPoint(SelectorManager.java:848) ~[jetty-io-8.1.5.v20120716.jar:8.1.5.v20120716]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.doUpdateKey(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:601) ~[jetty-io-8.1.5.v20120716.jar:8.1.5.v20120716]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.doSelect(SelectorManager.java:463) ~[jetty-io-8.1.5.v20120716.jar:8.1.5.v20120716]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$1.run(SelectorManager.java:285) ~[jetty-io-8.1.5.v20120716.jar:8.1.5.v20120716]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603) ~[jetty-util-8.1.5.v20120716.jar:8.1.5.v20120716]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538) ~[jetty-util-8.1.5.v20120716.jar:8.1.5.v20120716]
... 1 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you see reports `webSocketCode=1002`, and the code that does that disables the WebSocket transport, so fallback to long polling should work flawlessly.

The CometD test suite has a test for exactly this scenario.

Comment: What we see is the following: Oort tries to connect to another node 2 times until it noticed that Websocket doesn't work. Then it falls back to long polling which also fails the first time. After that, it seems like it can establish a connection, but the messages we'll send won't be forwarded to other nodes.

I guess it's not possible to get an answer for this with the infos I've provided so far cause it could be anything, but as soon as we (hopefully) found out the issue, I'll post it here.

Answer (score -1):

So this is only a debug message and not necessarly a "real" Exception shown?